# Visual Studio 2017 mangles my VSTS source control path

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to connect to VSTS in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 .  For server url, I manually type in https://myemployer.visualstudio.com it displays the url as https://myemployer.visualstudio.com/tfs.  If I do the same thing Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 the /tfs goes away once I type in the .com at the end of the path so it displays it as https://myemployer.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017, the reason it added `/tfs` is you are adding TFS server not VSTS. If you want to connect to your VSTS then please refer to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/connect-to-visual-studio-team-services#vs

In VS 2015, the UI is a bit different. If you type any LOCAL SERVER it will automatically recognize you are referring to TFS not VSTS so it added `/tfs` to your url. But when you type any URL start with `http://` it will recognize that this is public server and remove `/tfs` part.

Answer (score 0):

**For connecting VSTS projects in VS2017**, you should click add an account, and then enter email and password for you used in VSTS account.

[image]

**For connecting TFS projects in VS2017**, you should click Add TFS Server, then enter the TFS URL. You may enter VSTS URL here, so it shows https://myemployer.visualstudio.com/tfs.

[image]